# Need help defining "does not lead out from the system".

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I'm reading through a book on complex analysis, and I've come across the following definition,

"Addition and multiplication do not lead out from the system of complex numbers."

is this analogous to

"The system of complex numbers is closed under addition and multiplication"?

What does the term "do not lead out from the system" mean?

This is from the first paragraph of Lars Ahlfors's complex analysis 3rd edition.

Comment: More context might be necessary, but my first impression is yes, this sounds like an oddly-worded way to say that $\mathbb C$ is closed under addition and multiplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a poorly-phrased alternative description of the idea that the usual definition(s) of *closure under [operation]* are intended to capture.

For a book purporting to discuss a subject at the university level, it would be better to just use the appropriate terminology, since that facilitates consistency with other texts and resources, and makes it possible to identify the exact concept being referred to, if one is not currently aware of it.